# how to show last 20 entries from database

Tags: android

how to show last two entries from database  below is my code i need help any idea how to implement it  below is my complete code

```
       public List<JobSchmeModel> getALLCompJobs() {
    List<JobSchmeModel> compjobsList = new ArrayList<JobSchmeModel>();
    // Select All Query
    String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_COMPLETED_JOBS ;

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

    // looping through all rows and adding to list
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            JobSchmeModel jobmodel = new JobSchmeModel();
            jobmodel.setTime(cursor.getString(1));
            jobmodel.setPick(cursor.getString(2));
            jobmodel.setDestination(cursor.getString(3));
            jobmodel.setFare(cursor.getString(4));
            // Adding contact to list
            compjobsList.add(jobmodel);
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }

    db.close();

    return compjobsList;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use like

```
    if (cursor.moveToLast()) {
                do {
                    JobSchmeModel jobmodel = new JobSchmeModel();
                    jobmodel.setTime(cursor.getString(1));
                    jobmodel.setPick(cursor.getString(2));
                    jobmodel.setDestination(cursor.getString(3));
                    jobmodel.setFare(cursor.getString(4));
                    // Adding contact to list
                    compjobsList.add(jobmodel);
                } while (cursor.moveToPrevious());
            }
```

Comment: where u write code for only display last 20 entries

Answer (score 4):

```
"SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_COMPLETED_JOBS + " ORDER BY TIME DESC LIMIT 20"
```

Or order by a different column, maybe an auto incremented id? And swap 20 for 2, depending on what you actually want. There are two different amounts.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You could start to change your sql query like :

```
String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_COMPLETED_JOBS + "ORDER BY TIME DESC LIMIT 0, 2" ;
```

Comment: what does its mean "ORDER BY TIME DESC LIMIT 0, 2"

Comment: it means the order from the most recent to the oldest and from index to 2 ... So it's the two most recent. You can switch 2 to 20 if you'd like.